# Lisp: How to use let function to combine 2 lists into 1 list?

Tags: list, lisp, let

I want to create a function that could read my 2 input lists and combine what are inside the lists in to 1 lists, which allows me to use this 1 list for another function.

I have tried to use let function

```
    (defun sumup(p1 p2)
    (let ((sum (append(list  p1 p2)) ))
        (format t "the sum is ~a" sum)
        (poly sum)
    ) )
```

and when i enter the input lists

```
    (sumup+ '(5 (x 2)) '(3 (x 2)))
```

it gives results as

```
    the sum is ((5 (x 2)) (3 (x 2)))
    the poly term is (8 (x 2))
```

Here is the function poly, which will read the input list, and do the addition.

```
     (defun poly (p1)
      (let((x1(car(car(cdr(car p1))))) (x2(car(car(cdr(car(cdr p1))))))
           (e1(car(cdr(car(cdr(car p1)))))) (e2(car(cdr(car(cdr(car(cdr p1)))))))
           (c1(car(car p1))) (c2(car(car(cdr p1))))
           (remainder(cdr(cdr p1)))
           )
        (if(and(null remainder)(null c2))
            (format t "the poly term is (~a (~a ~a))" c1  x1  e1)
            ) 

        (if(and(equal x1 x2)(equal e1 e2))
            (poly(append (list(list(+ c1 c2)(list x1 e1))) remainder)))

           )
           )
```

so with this function poly

```
(poly '((5(x 3))(3(x 3))(1(x 3))(4(x 3))))
```

you will get

```
the poly term is (13 (x 3))
```

so my chosen format to represent 5x^2 will be (5(x 2)) this is why i quote.

the sumup function is able to combine 2 terms now,but if

```
(sumup+ '(5 (x 2)) '((3 (x 2)) (2 (x 2))))
```

i will get

```
the sum is ((5 (x 2)) ((3 (x 2)) (2 (x 2))))
```

how can i change it to be `((5 (x 2)) (3 (x 2)) (2 (x 2))` which can be use for `poly` function?

Comment: `sum` is a lexical variable, which is local to the `let` form in the `sumup` function and private to it. This means that the `sum` variable is only visible to forms contained inside the `let` form which binds the variable. `sum` is not visible outside of the `let`, and therefore it isn't visible outside of the function which contains the let.  `let` does **not** mean *"let it be known that this symbol refers to this value **everywhere** in this program"*.   For that, you can use a global variable (`defvar`, `defparameter`, `defconstant`).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, sorry i did not make it clear as the above code I wanted to show I thought sum will work as a list. I tried to use sum inside sumup function and let form, and still, SUM is not a list.

Comment: What does `poly` do? Replace `poly` with `listp` and `T` is returned, indicating that `sum` is, in fact, a list (tested in .CLISP 2.49)

Comment: @Kaz is it possible to give an example of how to use the backquote? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @mesue Maybe some of the material in the comments can be assembled into an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `'(sum)` denotes a list literal. It is a shorthand for the `quote` operator, and means exactly the same thing as `(quote (sum))`.

The quote operator suppresses evaluation of its argument as an expression and produces the argument literally; i.e. it means "don't try to call a function called `sum`; just give me the actual list `(sum)`: a one element list containing the symbol `sum`".

So for instance `(quote (+ 2 2))` or, using the usual shorthand, `'(+ 2 2)` returns `(+ 2 2)`, literally. If we drop the quote, and evaluate `(+ 2 2)` then we get `4`.

Now if we take `'(sum)` and simply drop the quote, it won't work, because now we're evaluating the form `(sum)` which expresses a call to a function whose name is `sum`, with no arguments. Of course, no such function exists, so the call is erroneous.

There is a special kind of "energized quote" in Lisp which resembles the regular quote. It is called [backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm). To use the backquote, we replace the apostrophe `'` shorthand with a backtick: `` ` ``.

Like quote, [backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) suppresses evaluation. However, inside a backquote, we can indicate elements which are exceptions to the "do not evaluate" rule, by preceding them with the comma, like this:

```
`(,sum)
```

If we have a variable called `sum` which holds a list (or any other object) and in that scope we evaluate the above backquote, that backquote will compute a list of one element which contains that object. Exactly as if we evaluated the expression `(list sum)`.

More complicated quasiquote example:

```
(let ((a "hello")
      (b 42))
  `(1 2 3 ,a 4 ,b b ,(+ 2 2) (+ 2 2)))

-> (1 2 3 "hello" 4 42 b 4 (+ 2 2))
```

The objects inside the backquote not preceded by a comma are all taken literally: the `b` is not evaluated as a variable but stays `b`, the `(+ 2 2)` stays `(+ 2 2)` and isn't reduced to 4, unlike the `,(+ 2 2)`.

Incidentally, inside the `poly` function, you have this expression:

```
(append (list (list (+ c1 c2) (list x1 e1))) remainder)
```

This is a little hard to read. Even though no quoted material is being used, it is still an excellent target for the application of the backquote. With backquote, we can rewrite the expression like this:

```
`((,(+ c1 c2) (,x1 ,e1)) ,@remainder)
```

All the distracting clutter of the `append` and `list` calls goes away, and we just see the shape of the list being constructed.

> Technical note: the backquote isn't a shorthand for any specific form syntax in Common Lisp. Whereas `'X` means `(quote X)`, as discussed, `` `X `` doesn't have such a correspondence; how it works is different in different implementations of Common Lisp. The comma also doesn't have a specific target syntax. In the Lisp dialect known as Scheme, `` `X `` corresponds to `(quasiquote X)` and `,Y` corresponds to `(unquote Y)`. This is defined by the Scheme language and so is that way in all implementations. Backquote is also known as "quasiquote", especially among Scheme programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming defun implies common lisp. Append is defined [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm).

((5 (x 2))) is a list containing the list (5 (x 2)).

I suspect you are looking for

```
(sumup (5 (x 2)) (3 (x 2)) )
```

On the other hand, poly is being called with a quoted list of a single argument, so it's possible you actually want:

```
(poly sum)
```

Overall, I think we need to see poly. I'm not clear why you're quoting everything.

Comment: thanks for helping, the reason for quoting is that i want to keep everything  in form as (constant (x constant)), this is my chosen way to represent a term like 5x^2 is (5 (x 2)), so basically, the poly will compare the power and term to check if they are the same and do the addition. so the above problem is based on my syntax